# Looking for a tool like "IP Personality" to defeat OS fingerprinting for recent Linux kernels

Tags: linux, networking, operating-system

I am looking for a way to defeat `nmap` OS-fingerprinting. This [article](https://nmap.org/misc/defeat-nmap-osdetect.html) describes a few approaches and mentions the tool [IP Personality](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ippersonality/?), which seems quite promising because it can trick `nmap` to detect a certain OS. However, the most recent version of this tool only works for the Linux 2.4 kernel.

I've been googling for a long time to find a tool that is capable of making `nmap` detect a different OS for more recent Linux kernels but couldn't find any.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

I too am looking for something similar to IP Personality.

I'm not sure if it meets your requirements, but [honeyd](http://www.honeyd.org/) can do similar.  You can set a "personality" in the configuration such as:

`set default personality "Linux 2.2.14"`